# Testing with Chai "should.exist" not working with async

Tags: javascript, chai

All the [documentation](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/) doesn't use async... same with stack overflow questions.

```
it('Create a customer', async () => {
  const createCustomer = await Customer.create({ email: 'test@gmail.com' });
  createCustomer.should.exist;
});
```

Here's my error

```
2) Customers Server Create a customer:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'exist' of undefined
```

Here's the import, just in case.

```
import { expect, should } from 'chai';
```

Other info: 'expect' does work. 'Should' does not.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `should` at the start of your assertion chain, you will need to call it. The convention is:

```
const should = chai.should()
```

Or, as the documentation has it written:

```
var should = require('chai').should() //actually call the function
```